# Should my classification object be black or white inline

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, shapes

I have a simple question. I am doing 2D shape recognition using Keras. I have these sample images I have generated using cv2:

[image: Quarter Circle]
Quarter Circle

[image: Cross]
Cross

[image: Rectangle]
Rectangle.

I was wondering if I should do a black background with white object or black object with white background?

Does it even matter?

Answer (score 1):

from your training data your validation accuracy is almost 97% so you should get something near that whhen you evaluate your test set.
First, set shuffle=False in you test generator.
below is the code to make predictions, get accuracy, confusion matrix and classification report

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

def predictor(model,test_gen):
    classes=list(test_gen.class_indices.keys())
    class_count=len(classes)
    preds=model.predict(test_gen, verbose=1)
    errors=0
    pred_indices=[]
    test_count =len(preds)    
    for i, p in enumerate (preds):
        pred_index=np.argmax(p)
        pred_indices.append(pred_index)
        true_index= test_gen.labels[i]    
        if  pred_index != true_index:        
            errors +=1 
    accuracy = (test_count-errors)*100/test_count
    ytrue=np.array(test_gen.labels, dtype='int')
    ypred=np.array(pred_indices, dtype='int')    
    msg=f'There were {errors} errors in {test_count} tests for an accuracy of {accuracy:6.2f} '
    print (msg)
    cm = confusion_matrix(ytrue, ypred )
    # plot the confusion matrix
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
 sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
    plt.xticks(np.arange(class_count)+.5, classes, rotation=90)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(class_count)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
    plt.xlabel("Predicted")
    plt.ylabel("Actual")
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.show()
    clr = classification_report(ytrue, ypred, target_names=classes, digits= 4) # create classification report
    print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
    return 
predictor(loaded_model,test_generator)
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing function! When shuffle is False, I get a very good accuracy. But when it is True I get terrible accuracy. What might be the cause of this?